# Addig global parameters to Data factory using bicep

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-bicep

I can't add global parameters to Azure Data Factory using bicep. The deployment runs fine but the global parameter list in Data Factory is empty.

I used this code:

```
resource dataFactory 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories@2018-06-01' = {
name: name
identity: {
  type: 'SystemAssigned'
}
properties: {
  globalParameters: {
    environment: {
      type: 'String'
      value: 'dev'
      }
    }
  }
location: location
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

In my dev environment it's enabled with Git configuration.

Comment: Does your data factory is enabled with git configuration ?

Comment: Yes, it's added with git configuration

Comment: It works if I don't add repo configuration. Is it possible to add repo configuration after deployment of the datafactory using bicep?

Comment: @user1005448- You can do it either by updating your existing bicep file used for data factory creation with repo configuration and rerun/redeploy the entire template. 
Alternatively, you can make use of `az datafactory configure factory repo` [cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/datafactory?view=azure-cli-latest#az-datafactory-configure-factory-repo) to update the repo configuration.

Comment: If I rerun with repo configuration then my global parameters are gone again. What are the relationship between the global parameters and repo configuration?

Comment: Can you [switch to live mode](https://i.imgur.com/4F0PGFG.png) and check whether the global parameters are showing up or not ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/author-global-parameters), you need to configure git configuration in your ARM template to create the global-parameters.

Instead of using `Microsoft.DataFactory/factories` you need to use `Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/globalParameters` in your bicep template.

```
"Microsoft.DataFactory/factories": {
"properties": {
"globalParameters": {
"*": {
"value": "="
},
.............

and instead added:

"Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/globalparameters": {
"properties": {
"*": "="
}
}
```

For more information, refer to this sample bicep schema [shared here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.datafactory/factories/globalparameters?pivots=deployment-language-bicep)

Comment: I'm also trying that now but still same result. Seems like it has something to do whether devops configuration is enabled or not. I don't see why those are connected.